# Python: write to csv, create headers for dynamic number of output columns

Tags: python, list, csv

I have the following variables:

`InputNumber` (user defined from 1 to 6),

`nameofstate` (list of 2 names, let's call them X and Y)

`list[state][protein][counts][x] 
list[state][protein][counts][y]`, where x and y are lists that will equal the length of InputNumber

So where `InputNumber = 3`

```
list[state][protein][counts][x] = [a,b,c]
list[state][protein][counts][y] = [r,s,t]
```

Where `InputNumber = 4`

```
list[state][protein][counts][x] = [a,b,c,d]
list[state][protein][counts][y] = [r,s,t,u]
```

I want to create new columns for these counts, but I can't figure out how to make dynamic column headers:

```
Name    X1  X2  X3  Y1  Y2  Y3  Name    X1  X2 X3 X4 Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4        
Name    a   b   c   r   s   t   Name    a   b  c  d  r  s  t  u
```

Here is the code I have for my headers:

```
    listheaders = [str(nameofstate[0]) + str(x + 1) for x in range(0, InputNumber), str(nameofstate[1]) + str(x + 1) for x in range(0, InputNumber)]
    with open("PATH and NAME" + ".csv", 'w') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        wr.writerow(["Name", (i for i in listheaders[0]), (e for e in listheaders[1]])
        for name in anotherlist:
            perform the same iterative code
```

My problem is with the generator expression - I can't wrap my head around how to tell it to unpack the entries in `listheaders`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. str("Name 1" + x) for x in len(listQ), something like that?

Comment: You should show the expected result, because `wr.writerow` with 3 parameters just gives a syntax error, and if you make it a tuple, you will get exactly 3 columns.

Comment: I rewrote the question; could you take another look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow everything that's happening in your question, but it appears that you're trying to do too much in listheaders. If I understand correctly, you want to use a helper function to construct

```
def _get_header_list(name_of_state, input_number):
    return ['{}{}'.format(name_of_state, str(x)) for x in range(1, input_number + 1)]

first_list = _get_header_list(nameofstate[0], InputNumber)
second_list = _get_header_list(nameofstate[1], InputNumber)
```

then later...

```
wr.writerow(['Name'] + first_list + second_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying; I re-wrote the question, would you take a look? Headers are what I'm after; the column contents will have the same structure. Basically, I'm having trouble with the writerow expression, telling it to unpack list contents...